# Contenteditable text editor and cursor position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

How can I (using jquery or other) insert html at the cursor/caret position of my contenteditable div:

```
<div contenteditable="true">Hello world</div>
```

For example, if the cursor/caret was between "hello" and "world" and the user then clicked a button, eg "insert image", then using javascript, something like `<img src=etc etc>` would be inserted between "hello" and "world". I hope I've made this clear =S

Example code would be greatly appreciated, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11):

The following function will insert a DOM node (element or text node) at the cursor position in all the mainstream desktop browsers:

```
function insertNodeAtCursor(node) {
    var sel, range, html;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            sel.getRangeAt(0).insertNode(node);
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        html = (node.nodeType == 3) ? node.data : node.outerHTML;
        range.pasteHTML(html);
    }
}
```

If you would rather insert an HTML string:

```
function insertHtmlAtCursor(html) {
    var sel, range, node;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            node = range.createContextualFragment(html);
            range.insertNode(node);
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(html);
    }
}
```

I've adapted this from my answer to a similar question: [How to find cursor position in a contenteditable DIV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213376/how-to-find-cursor-position-in-a-contenteditable-div/2213514#2213514)

Comment: insertHtmlAtCursor() works great for need but after insertion the cursor is left inside the html.  Can you change it so that it's placed just after the html that was inserted?

Answer (score 2):

With `contenteditable` you should use [`execCommand`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand.html).

Try `document.execCommand('insertImage', false, 'image.jpg')` or `document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<img src="image.jpg" alt="" />')`. The second doesn't work in older IE.

Comment: Thanks - that works great in Chrome.  I had to use insertHTML in order to add `alt` tags to an image; insertImage failed.

Comment: @Znarkus, This is not working in safari for iOS application. It is not inserting html strings containing image tage or attachment at the cursor position. Can you suggest some solution.

Answer (score 0):

in this code i have just replace html code with **(")** to  **(')**

use this syntax:

```
$("div.second").html("your html code and replace with (")to(')  ");
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend the use of the jquery plugin [a-tools](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/a-tools)

This plugin has seven functions:

```
* getSelection – return start, end position, length of the selected text and the selected text. return start=end=caret position if text is not selected;
* replaceSelection – replace selected text with a given string;
* setSelection – select text in a given range (startPosition and endPosition);
* countCharacters – count amount of all characters;
* insertAtCaretPos – insert text at current caret position;
* setCaretPos – set cursor at caret position (1 = beginning, -1 = end);
* setMaxLength – set maximum length of input field. Also provides callback function if limit is reached. Note: The function has to have a number as input. Positive value for setting of limit and negative number for removing of limit.
```

The one that you need is **insertAtCaretPos**:

```
$("#textarea").insertAtCaretPos("<img src=etc etc>");
```

There might be a draw-back: this plugins only works with textarea en input:text elements, so there may be conflicts with contenteditable.

Comment: *"There might be a draw-back: this plugins only works with textarea en input:text elements, so there may be conflicts with contenteditable."* You're correct. It won't work at all.