# contenteditable removeFormat on images

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I am trying to sync a contenteditable DIV with a textarea which is part of form.

I am pulling the `innerHTML` from the DIV but I would like to be able to remove nested formatting from the `img` tags (bold, italics, underline etc).  It would probably be easier to remove any formatting on images before accessing innerHTML of the div as opposed to using regex on the html.

I could use:

```
    document.execCommand('removeFormat', false, null);
```

*But how might I only remove formatting on images?*

(Also I need to use ALT tags on the images and it seems impossible to accomplish with `execCommand` / `insertImage`.  Is this correct?  I ended up following the suggestion on [Contenteditable text editor and cursor position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937975/contenteditable-text-editor-and-cursor-position/9575021#9575021) and am using `insertHTML`)

Thanks much!

Comment: What kind of image formatting? Why not walk the DOM to remove formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @tim-down suggestion here is my attempt at navigating the DOM and removing text formatting from IMG tags.

Bonus will awarded for more elegant solutions.

Working example here:  http://jsfiddle.net/tjzGg/

```
function setCaret() {
    var el = document.getElementById("editable");
    recurseDOM(el);
    el.focus();
}

function recurseDOM(el) {
    var nIndex = 0;
    var elNode = el.childNodes[nIndex];
    while (elNode) {
        var tag = elNode.tagName;
        if (tag) {
            if (tag.toUpperCase() == 'IMG') {
                var range = document.createRange();
                var sel = window.getSelection();
                range.selectNode(elNode);
                sel.removeAllRanges();
                sel.addRange(range);
                document.execCommand('removeFormat', false, null);
            } else if (elNode.childElementCount) {
                recurseDOM(elNode);
            }
        }
        nIndex++;
        elNode = el.childNodes[nIndex];
    }
}
```