# How can i determine the position of textarea cursor relative to the window in x,y?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a javascript code editor just for learning and I am doing a great job so far. The only thing is that I wanna place the autocomplete box in a position relative to the text cursor in textarea. So how can I determine the cursor position relative to the upper left corner of the window ?

Something else please, how can i capture the tab & enter keys press in a textarea ?

I am using a semi-transparent textarea (semi to keep the cursor blinking) with underlying div to enable code highlighting later on. Is this the best technique to do that ? Or there is a way to make textarea accept rich text or HTML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you can do all that without a textarea. Read up on the [contentEditable](http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-contenteditable) property. Here's a [demo.](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable) This is how the Google Docs editor is implemented, incidentally. And here's [a stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213376/how-to-find-cursor-position-in-a-contenteditable-div) dealing with finding the cursor position in a contentEditable div.