# How to get text cursor position using javascript

Tags: javascript, cursor, position

this is my code ,i fill space all in div ,(use jquery):

```
<div id="a" style="position:absolute;top:300px;width:100px;height:100px;background:red;color:black;word-wrap:break-word;">
    <div id='a2' contenteditable=true ></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    String.prototype.repeat = function(n) {
        return new Array(1 + parseInt(n, 10)).join(this);
    }

    var s=$('#a').width()/4*$('#a').height()/19;
    $('#a2').html('&nbsp;'.repeat($('#a').width()/4*parseInt($('#a').height()/19)))

    $('#a2').click(function(){
        alert('sss')
    })

</script>
```

so how can i get the text cursor position when i click somewhere in 'a2' div

the demo is http://jsfiddle.net/KBnKc/

thanks

Comment: What cursor, the text or the mouse one?

Comment: @Pekka Mouse - the demo is just a red box.

Comment: @Šime true, but it contains a div with `contenteditable=true`.

Comment: sorry, i want to get the text cursor ,

Comment: What do you want to do with the caret position once you've got it?

Comment: i want to do editor that you can use it like a paper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>You can use the [pageX](http://api.jquery.com/event.pageX/) and [pageY](http://api.jquery.com/event.pageY/) property of the jQuery [event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) object:</strike>

```
$('#a2').click(function(e) {
    alert(e.pageX + ", " + e.pageY);
});
```

The returned coordinates are relative to the top left of the document.

You might want to use the [A-Tools](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/a-tools) plugin, more specifically its `getSelection()` method. It returns the caret position if no text is selected.

By the way, the "text cursor" is called the caret :)

**EDIT:** The aforementioned plugin will not work with `contenteditable` `<div>`elements. While looking for another solution, I found [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213376/how-to-find-cursor-position-in-a-contenteditable-div/2213514#2213514) which is a duplicate of yours. Maybe the responses there can help you.

Comment: sorry , i want to get the text cursor .

Comment: édéric Are you sure that getSelection() works on contenteditable DIV elements?

Answer (score 0):

you can use **Prototype.js** to get mouse position:

```
var x, y;
function getCoordinatesInsideElement(e)
{
    x = Event.pointerX(e);
    y = Event.pointerY(e);
    /* DO-SOMETHING */
}
```

See prototype reference at: http://api.prototypejs.org/