# Finding the current caret position in a contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a **contenteditable div**. I want to colorize specific text (which is like **A4**, **D12** etc) while typing.

So on each keypress i check the content of `div`, find out the tokens(A4,D11 etc) and wrap them into `span`.

So `abcd+A6` will get converted as `abcd+<span color=#some-color>A6</span>`

Now i want to know the current caret position. Let say cursor is after **A** inside the `span`,

but when i do

```
sel=window.getSelection()
pos = sel.anchorOffset
```

i am getting `pos=1` that is the position of the caret in the `span` element But i want the caret positon relative to the `div` element (it should be `pos=6` in this case)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213376/how-to-find-cursor-position-in-a-contenteditable-div

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sel = window.getSelection();
pos = sel.focusOffset;
```

You can see more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection.focusNode)