# Chrome firing onClick when space typed in contenteditable button

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have a button with `contenteditable=true`. I can edit the text just fine, but I cannot type spaces in Chrome. When I hit spacebar, Chrome instead fires an onClick event on the button. Safari, however, inserts a space just as you would expect.

With this code, trying to type a space while editing the button triggers the alert in Chrome.

```
<button 
    contenteditable="true" 
    onclick="alert('wtf?');">Edit me!</button>
```

Fiddle with this code: http://jsfiddle.net/Jrt8w/1/

Why is Chrome pretending that was a click event? And how can I convince it to instead insert a space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
event.preventDefault()
```

is what saved me. In the keyPress function have an event.preventDefault and the onClick should not be called.

Answer (score 4):

This is a harder problem than appears. There doesn't seem to be any way to turn off the space key "clicking" the button, so this is an attempt at emulation:

```
<button 
    contenteditable="true" 
    onclick="if (!event.x && !event.y && !event.clientX && !event.clientY) {event.preventDefault(); insertHtmlAtCursor('&nbsp;');} else {alert('wtf?');}">Edit me!</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function insertHtmlAtCursor(html) {
    var range, node;
    if (window.getSelection && window.getSelection().getRangeAt) {
        range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        node = range.createContextualFragment(html);
        range.insertNode(node);
        window.getSelection().collapseToEnd();
        window.getSelection().modify('move', 'forward', 'character');
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(html);
        document.selection.collapseToEnd();
        document.selection.modify('move', 'forward', 'character');
    }
}
</script>
```

You can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5Fyzy/1/).

I copied the meat of my code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2213514/468405). Please note that I've only tested in Chrome. Not sure if it will work in IE, and if not, I'd use a library like [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/), mentioned in the answer I linked above. Either way, this should give you a good starting point.

Comment: This is halfway there. `preventDefault()` doesn't seem to actually stop the click event, though.

Comment: The issue is that it still presses the button. Inserting the space works, yes, but the button still gets clicked.

Comment: suppperb Joel now i am your big fan.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Firefox 31 and 32. Typing space opened the alert-box. Solution: Replace onclick with onmousedown.